# Android Studio in macOS does not recognize physical device after hitting 'run'

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I have been testing my Android app in my Samsung Galaxy S8 for the past few weeks from Android Studio's ADB without any issues.

After a while a switched to test the app in Android Studio's built-in emulators.

Then I swiched back to test it in my Samsung and it won't install the app.

I would plug the phone to the laptop, Android studio's ADB would recognize the device, I hit run, and after the Gradle build, as soon as it goes into 'install', the process stops, and prints the **following**:

```
10/16 14:34:46: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-G950F.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/david.rajchenberg/Desktop/JByte Studios/Practice/SpeechToText-master/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'device 'ce031713eb784b1f03' not found'
Retry
```

I have tried the following:

- Uninstall and reinstall Android studio
- Turn off and back on my device
- Switch USB cables (I only have so many)
- Switch USB ports
- Clean project
- Build project
- Unplug and and plug back in the device and wait until Android Studio recognizes it again
- I checked the phone's connectivity to the laptop and its okay. I am able to move files in and out of the device, to the computer and back.
- Developer options is activated with USB debugging

**To summarize**
Android Studio recognizes the device as soon as I plug it into the laptop, but as soon as I hit run and gradle is done building, as soon as the process goes into install, the connection between Android Studio and the device is lost, while the device, is still connected to the computer (and able to move files in an out with ease).

I run Android Studio 4.1 on a MacBook Pro with macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Tried updating the platform tools (adb) from the sdk manager?

Comment: tried that but it did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to kill the adb from Activity Monitor (Mac) and restart Android Studio. Apparently that did the trick